# pjsua_call_make_call over TCP takes up to 10 seconds for Invite to reach other user

Tags: pjsip, avaya

I'm fairly new to PJSIP, and am using PJSIP 2.5.5 to build a SIP Client into an existing application.  Every thing works fine when I am using an Asterisk server, but when connecting to an Avaya the outgoing call takes up to 10 seconds to connect to the another client.  Calling from media5-fone to my app does not have this Issue, so I suspect a configuration issue on my side.  I am using TCP transport, UDP has been disabled on the Server.

Is anyone able to help out?

In this case it took about 6 seconds for the other app to receive the Invite.

Thanks

Here is the Sip Trace

```
2016-10-12 18:06:07.568 JCTComms[755:200829] Reconnecting
18:06:07.572 os_core_unix.c !pjlib 2.5.5 for POSIX initialized
18:06:07.583 sip_endpoint.c  .Creating endpoint instance...
18:06:07.584          pjlib  .select() I/O Queue created (0x14bae144)
18:06:07.585 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-msg-print" registered
18:06:07.585 sip_transport.  .Transport manager created.
18:06:07.585   pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: NULL --> CREATED
18:06:07.587 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-log" registered
18:06:07.587 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-tsx-layer" registered
18:06:07.587 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-stateful-util" registered
18:06:07.587 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-ua" registered
18:06:07.588 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-100rel" registered
18:06:07.588 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua" registered
18:06:07.590 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-invite" registered
18:06:07.644 coreaudio_dev.  .. dev_id 0: iPhone IO device  (in=1, out=1) 8000Hz
18:06:07.649 coreaudio_dev.  ..core audio initialized
18:06:07.651          pjlib  ..select() I/O Queue created (0x14bb9814)
18:06:07.651  speex_codec.c  ..Adjusting quality to 5 for uwb
18:06:07.661   conference.c  ..Creating conference bridge with 73 ports
18:06:07.663   Master/sound  ..Using delay buffer with WSOLA.
18:06:07.669 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-evsub" registered
18:06:07.670 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-presence" registered
18:06:07.670        evsub.c  .Event pkg "presence" registered by mod-presence
18:06:07.670 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-mwi" registered
18:06:07.670        evsub.c  .Event pkg "message-summary" registered by mod-mwi
18:06:07.671 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-refer" registered
18:06:07.671        evsub.c  .Event pkg "refer" registered by mod-refer
18:06:07.672 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-pres" registered
18:06:07.672 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-im" registered
18:06:07.673 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-pjsua-options" registered
18:06:07.673   pjsua_core.c  .1 SIP worker threads created
18:06:07.673   pjsua_core.c  .pjsua version 2.5.5 for iPhone OS-9.3.2/arm-iPad3,6/iOS-SDK-10.0 initialized
18:06:07.674   pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: CREATED --> INIT
18:06:07.675 sip_endpoint.c  Module "mod-default-handler" registered
18:06:07.678   pjsua_core.c  SIP UDP socket reachable at 172.30.0.202:5060
18:06:07.679  udp0x14bab000  SIP UDP transport started, published address is 172.30.0.202:5060
18:06:07.680    pjsua_acc.c  Adding account: id=<sip:172.30.0.202:5060>
18:06:07.680    pjsua_acc.c  .Account <sip:172.30.0.202:5060> added with id 0
18:06:07.681    pjsua_acc.c  Modifying account 0
18:06:07.682    pjsua_acc.c  Acc 0: setting online status to 1..
18:06:07.685     tcptp:5060  SIP TCP listener ready for incoming connections at 172.30.0.202:5060
18:06:07.685    pjsua_acc.c  Adding account: id=<sip:172.30.0.202:5060;transport=TCP>
18:06:07.686    pjsua_acc.c  .Account <sip:172.30.0.202:5060;transport=TCP> added with id 1
18:06:07.686    pjsua_acc.c  Modifying account 1
18:06:07.687    pjsua_acc.c  Acc 1: setting online status to 1..
18:06:07.687   pjsua_core.c  PJSUA state changed: INIT --> STARTING
18:06:07.688 sip_endpoint.c  .Module "mod-unsolicited-mwi" registered
18:06:07.690   pjsua_core.c  .PJSUA state changed: STARTING --> RUNNING
18:06:08.498    pjsua_acc.c !Deleting account 1..
18:06:08.498    pjsua_acc.c  .Account id 1 deleted
18:06:08.498    pjsua_acc.c  Adding account: id=sip:4742@172.30.38.20
18:06:08.498    pjsua_acc.c  .Account sip:4742@172.30.38.20 added with id 1
18:06:08.498    pjsua_acc.c  .Acc 1: setting registration..
18:06:08.505 tcpc0x14c36614  ..TCP client transport created
18:06:08.505 tcpc0x14c36614  ..TCP transport 172.30.0.202:55093 is connecting to 172.30.38.20:5060...
18:06:08.505    pjsua_acc.c  ..Contact for acc 1 updated for SIP outbound: <sip:4742@172.30.0.202:55093;transport=TCP;ob>;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000035569cf7>"
18:06:08.505       endpoint  ..Request msg REGISTER/cseq=63903 (tdta0x14c34600) created.
18:06:08.507  tsx0x14c31a64  ...Transaction created for Request msg REGISTER/cseq=63904 (tdta0x14c34600)
18:06:08.507  tsx0x14c31a64  ..Sending Request msg REGISTER/cseq=63904 (tdta0x14c34600) in state Null
18:06:08.507  sip_resolve.c  ...Target '172.30.38.20:5060' type=TCP resolved to '172.30.38.20:5060' type=TCP (TCP transport)
18:06:08.515   pjsua_core.c  ...TX 699 bytes Request msg REGISTER/cseq=63904 (tdta0x14c34600) to TCP 172.30.38.20:5060:
REGISTER sip:172.30.38.20:5060;transport=tcp SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 172.30.0.202:55093;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj6MS-nUSrO1GmBXb-L59VSVHJw3Orv548;alias

Route: <sip:172.30.38.20:5060;transport=tcp;lr>

Max-Forwards: 70

From: <sip:4742@172.30.38.20>;tag=5ODLRfzWTt.cH9VgEEpJsTGgq2pJiVic

To: <sip:4742@172.30.38.20>

Call-ID: WK50hvGirkAhjIkmXO0vCktKqnFBdoO2

CSeq: 63904 REGISTER

User-Agent: JCT Messenger

Supported: outbound, path

Contact: <sip:4742@172.30.0.202:55093;transport=TCP;ob>;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000035569cf7>"

Expires: 720

Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS

Content-Length:  0




--end msg--
18:06:08.515  tsx0x14c31a64  ...State changed from Null to Calling, event=TX_MSG
18:06:08.515    pjsua_acc.c  ..Acc 1: Registration sent
18:06:08.620 tcpc0x14c36614 !TCP transport 172.30.0.202:55093 is connected to 172.30.38.20:5060
18:06:08.620    pjsua_app.c  SIP TCP transport is connected to [172.30.38.20:5060]
18:06:08.721 sip_endpoint.c  Processing incoming message: Response msg 401/REGISTER/cseq=63904 (rdata0x14c367d4)
18:06:08.721   pjsua_core.c  .RX 593 bytes Response msg 401/REGISTER/cseq=63904 (rdata0x14c367d4) from TCP 172.30.38.20:5060:
SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized

Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 172.30.0.202:55093;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj6MS-nUSrO1GmBXb-L59VSVHJw3Orv548;alias

From: <sip:4742@172.30.38.20>;tag=5ODLRfzWTt.cH9VgEEpJsTGgq2pJiVic

Call-ID: WK50hvGirkAhjIkmXO0vCktKqnFBdoO2

CSeq: 63904 REGISTER

User-Agent: IP Office 9.0.6.0 build 979

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,NOTIFY,INFO,SUBSCRIBE,REGISTER,PUBLISH

WWW-Authenticate: Digest nonce="0a00921e107b3c39d659",realm="ipoffice",algorithm=MD5

Supported: timer

Server: IP Office 9.0.6.0 build 979

To: <sip:4742@172.30.38.20>;tag=9f1e75e41356afe2

Content-Length: 0




--end msg--
18:06:08.721  tsx0x14c31a64  .Incoming Response msg 401/REGISTER/cseq=63904 (rdata0x14c367d4) in state Calling
18:06:08.721  tsx0x14c31a64  ..State changed from Calling to Completed, event=RX_MSG
18:06:08.727  tsx0x153de264  ....Transaction created for Request msg REGISTER/cseq=63905 (tdta0x14c34600)
18:06:08.727  tsx0x153de264  ...Sending Request msg REGISTER/cseq=63905 (tdta0x14c34600) in state Null
18:06:08.727       endpoint  ....Request msg REGISTER/cseq=63905 (tdta0x14c34600): skipping target resolution because address is already set
18:06:08.727   pjsua_core.c  ....TX 889 bytes Request msg REGISTER/cseq=63905 (tdta0x14c34600) to TCP 172.30.38.20:5060:
REGISTER sip:172.30.38.20:5060;transport=tcp SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 172.30.0.202:55093;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj-YmZsrRRcqdiFpf.sh4sZVJP3WmXXnJE;alias

Route: <sip:172.30.38.20:5060;transport=tcp;lr>

Max-Forwards: 70

From: <sip:4742@172.30.38.20>;tag=5ODLRfzWTt.cH9VgEEpJsTGgq2pJiVic

To: <sip:4742@172.30.38.20>

Call-ID: WK50hvGirkAhjIkmXO0vCktKqnFBdoO2

CSeq: 63905 REGISTER

User-Agent: JCT Messenger

Supported: outbound, path

Contact: <sip:4742@172.30.0.202:55093;transport=TCP;ob>;reg-id=1;+sip.instance="<urn:uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000035569cf7>"

Expires: 720

Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS

Authorization: Digest username="4742", realm="ipoffice", nonce="0a00921e107b3c39d659", uri="sip:172.30.38.20:5060;transport=tcp", response="b5ae24de8dd6e0525f44387b3cb772f6", algorithm=MD5

Content-Length:  0




--end msg--
18:06:08.736  tsx0x153de264  ....State changed from Null to Calling, event=TX_MSG
18:06:08.744  tsx0x14c31a64  Timeout timer event
18:06:08.744  tsx0x14c31a64  .State changed from Completed to Terminated, event=TIMER
18:06:08.744  tsx0x14c31a64  Timeout timer event
18:06:08.744  tsx0x14c31a64  .State changed from Terminated to Destroyed, event=TIMER
18:06:08.744  tsx0x14c31a64  Transaction destroyed!
18:06:08.841 sip_endpoint.c  Processing incoming message: Response msg 200/REGISTER/cseq=63905 (rdata0x14c367d4)
18:06:08.841   pjsua_core.c  .RX 605 bytes Response msg 200/REGISTER/cseq=63905 (rdata0x14c367d4) from TCP 172.30.38.20:5060:
SIP/2.0 200 OK

Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 172.30.0.202:55093;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj-YmZsrRRcqdiFpf.sh4sZVJP3WmXXnJE;alias

From: <sip:4742@172.30.38.20>;tag=5ODLRfzWTt.cH9VgEEpJsTGgq2pJiVic

Call-ID: WK50hvGirkAhjIkmXO0vCktKqnFBdoO2

CSeq: 63905 REGISTER

User-Agent: IP Office 9.0.6.0 build 979

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,REFER,NOTIFY,INFO,SUBSCRIBE,REGISTER,PUBLISH

Contact: <sip:4742@172.30.0.202:55093;transport=TCP;ob>

Date: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 07:35:58 GMT

Expires: 180

Supported: timer

Server: IP Office 9.0.6.0 build 979

To: <sip:4742@172.30.38.20>;tag=8bf9216eda9c9390

Content-Length: 0




--end msg--
18:06:08.841  tsx0x153de264  .Incoming Response msg 200/REGISTER/cseq=63905 (rdata0x14c367d4) in state Calling
18:06:08.841  tsx0x153de264  ..State changed from Calling to Completed, event=RX_MSG
18:06:08.844    pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP outbound status for acc 1 is not active
18:06:08.844    pjsua_acc.c  ....sip:4742@172.30.38.20: registration success, status=200 (OK), will re-register in 180 seconds
18:06:08.844  tsx0x153de264  Timeout timer event
18:06:08.844  tsx0x153de264  .State changed from Completed to Terminated, event=TIMER
18:06:08.844  tsx0x153de264  Timeout timer event
18:06:08.844  tsx0x153de264  .State changed from Terminated to Destroyed, event=TIMER
18:06:08.844 tdta0x14c34600  ..Destroying txdata Request msg REGISTER/cseq=63905 (tdta0x14c34600)
18:06:08.844  tsx0x153de264  Transaction destroyed!
18:06:35.866   pjsua_call.c !Making call with acc #1 to sip:4743@172.30.38.20
18:06:35.866    pjsua_aud.c  .Set sound device: capture=-1, playback=-2
18:06:35.866    pjsua_app.c  ..Turning sound device ON
18:06:35.866    pjsua_aud.c  ..Opening sound device (speaker + mic) PCM@16000/1/20ms
18:06:35.866 coreaudio_dev.  ...Using VoiceProcessingIO audio unit
18:06:36.096 coreaudio_dev.  ...core audio stream started
18:06:36.101  dlg0x153fe664  .UAC dialog created
18:06:36.101  dlg0x153fe664  ..Session count inc to 2 by mod-pjsua
18:06:36.101  pjsua_media.c  .Call 0: initializing media..
18:06:36.101  pjsua_media.c  ..RTP socket reachable at 172.30.0.202:4000
18:06:36.101  pjsua_media.c  ..RTCP socket reachable at 172.30.0.202:4001
18:06:36.102  pjsua_media.c  ..Media index 0 selected for audio call 0
18:06:36.102  dlg0x153fe664  ..Session count dec to 2 by mod-pjsua
18:06:36.102  dlg0x153fe664  .Module mod-invite added as dialog usage, data=0x1538d6e4
18:06:36.102  dlg0x153fe664  ..Session count inc to 4 by mod-invite
18:06:36.102  dlg0x153fe664  .Module mod-100rel added as dialog usage, data=0x1539c988
18:06:36.102  dlg0x153fe664  .100rel module attached
18:06:36.102  inv0x153fe664  .UAC invite session created for dialog dlg0x153fe664
18:06:36.102       endpoint  .Request msg INVITE/cseq=29601 (tdta0x15403800) created.
18:06:36.102  inv0x153fe664  ..Sending Request msg INVITE/cseq=29601 (tdta0x15403800)
18:06:36.102  dlg0x153fe664  ...Sending Request msg INVITE/cseq=29601 (tdta0x15403800)
18:06:36.106  tsx0x15405864  ....Transaction created for Request msg INVITE/cseq=29600 (tdta0x15403800)
18:06:36.106  tsx0x15405864  ...Sending Request msg INVITE/cseq=29600 (tdta0x15403800) in state Null
18:06:36.106  sip_resolve.c  ....Target '172.30.38.20:5060' type=TCP resolved to '172.30.38.20:5060' type=TCP (TCP transport)
18:06:36.106   pjsua_core.c  ....TX 1153 bytes Request msg INVITE/cseq=29600 (tdta0x15403800) to TCP 172.30.38.20:5060:
INVITE sip:4743@172.30.38.20 SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 172.30.0.202:55093;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjwHAvb0PCcoewU7nF.39cL2N5AiMAGrvG;alias

Max-Forwards: 70

From: sip:4742@172.30.38.20;tag=0kqd-cxo2dM8SFv05fxlJH8UGHzXdUZe

To: sip:4743@172.30.38.20

Contact: <sip:4742@172.30.0.202:55093;transport=TCP;ob>

Call-ID: NC.T6KcR7Rv-Sno23807LLcoBn1ZosfT

CSeq: 29600 INVITE

Route: <sip:172.30.38.20:5060;transport=tcp;lr>

Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS

Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub

Session-Expires: 1800

Min-SE: 90

User-Agent: JCT Messenger

Content-Type: application/sdp

Content-Length:   473



v=0

o=- 3685246596 3685246596 IN IP4 172.30.0.202

s=pjmedia

b=AS:84

t=0 0

a=X-nat:0

m=audio 4000 RTP/AVP 98 97 99 104 3 0 8 9 96

c=IN IP4 172.30.0.202

b=TIAS:64000

a=rtcp:4001 IN IP4 172.30.0.202

a=sendrecv

a=rtpmap:98 speex/16000

a=rtpmap:97 speex/8000

a=rtpmap:99 speex/32000

a=rtpmap:104 iLBC/8000

a=fmtp:104 mode=30

a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000

a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000

a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000

a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000

a=rtpmap:96 telephone-event/8000

a=fmtp:96 0-16


--end msg--
18:06:36.111  tsx0x15405864  ....State changed from Null to Calling, event=TX_MSG
18:06:36.111  dlg0x153fe664  .....Transaction tsx0x15405864 state changed to Calling
18:06:36.112    pjsua_app.c  .......Call 0 state changed to CALLING
18:06:36.116 coreaudio_dev. !Recorder thread started, (372 frames)
18:06:36.116 os_core_unix.c  Info: possibly re-registering existing thread
18:06:36.116 coreaudio_dev. !Player thread started, (372 frames)
18:06:42.828 sip_endpoint.c !Processing incoming message: Response msg 100/INVITE/cseq=29600 (rdata0x14c367d4)
18:06:42.830   pjsua_core.c  .RX 472 bytes Response msg 100/INVITE/cseq=29600 (rdata0x14c367d4) from TCP 172.30.38.20:5060:
SIP/2.0 100 Trying

Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 172.30.0.202:55093;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjwHAvb0PCcoewU7nF.39cL2N5AiMAGrvG;alias

From: <sip:4742@172.30.38.20>;tag=0kqd-cxo2dM8SFv05fxlJH8UGHzXdUZe

Call-ID: NC.T6KcR7Rv-Sno23807LLcoBn1ZosfT

CSeq: 29600 INVITE

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,INFO,REFER,NOTIFY,SUBSCRIBE,REGISTER,PUBLISH,UPDATE

Supported: timer,100rel

Server: IP Office 9.0.6.0 build 979

To: <sip:4743@172.30.38.20>;tag=a747f750afce40c6

Content-Length: 0




--end msg--
18:06:42.830  tsx0x15405864  .Incoming Response msg 100/INVITE/cseq=29600 (rdata0x14c367d4) in state Calling
18:06:42.830  tsx0x15405864  ..State changed from Calling to Proceeding, event=RX_MSG
18:06:42.830  dlg0x153fe664  ...Received Response msg 100/INVITE/cseq=29600 (rdata0x14c367d4)
18:06:42.830  dlg0x153fe664  ...Transaction tsx0x15405864 state changed to Proceeding
18:06:44.921 sip_endpoint.c  Processing incoming message: Response msg 180/INVITE/cseq=29600 (rdata0x14c367d4)
18:06:44.922   pjsua_core.c  .RX 607 bytes Response msg 180/INVITE/cseq=29600 (rdata0x14c367d4) from TCP 172.30.38.20:5060:
SIP/2.0 180 Ringing

Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 172.30.0.202:55093;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjwHAvb0PCcoewU7nF.39cL2N5AiMAGrvG;alias

From: <sip:4742@172.30.38.20>;tag=0kqd-cxo2dM8SFv05fxlJH8UGHzXdUZe

Call-ID: NC.T6KcR7Rv-Sno23807LLcoBn1ZosfT

CSeq: 29600 INVITE

Contact: "LNursecall03" <sip:4743@172.30.38.20:5060;transport=tcp>

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,INFO,REFER,NOTIFY,SUBSCRIBE,REGISTER,PUBLISH,UPDATE

P-Asserted-Identity: "LNursecall03" <sip:4743@172.30.38.20:5060>

Supported: timer,100rel

Server: IP Office 9.0.6.0 build 979

To: <sip:4743@172.30.38.20>;tag=a747f750afce40c6

Content-Length: 0




--end msg--
18:06:44.922  tsx0x15405864  .Incoming Response msg 180/INVITE/cseq=29600 (rdata0x14c367d4) in state Proceeding
18:06:44.922  tsx0x15405864  ..State changed from Proceeding to Proceeding, event=RX_MSG
18:06:44.922  dlg0x153fe664  ...Received Response msg 180/INVITE/cseq=29600 (rdata0x14c367d4)
18:06:44.922  dlg0x153fe664  ....Route-set updated
18:06:44.922  dlg0x153fe664  ...Transaction tsx0x15405864 state changed to Proceeding
18:06:44.923    pjsua_aud.c  .....Conf connect: 1 --> 0
18:06:44.923   conference.c  ......Port 1 (ringback) transmitting to port 0 (iPhone IO device)
18:06:44.924    pjsua_app.c  .....Call 0 state changed to EARLY (180 Ringing)
18:06:46.467   pjsua_call.c !Call 0 hanging up: code=0..
18:06:46.467       endpoint  ..Request msg CANCEL/cseq=29600 (tdta0x14c51400) created.
18:06:46.467  inv0x153fe664  ..Sending Request msg CANCEL/cseq=29600 (tdta0x14c51400)
18:06:46.467  dlg0x153fe664  ...Sending Request msg CANCEL/cseq=29600 (tdta0x14c51400)
18:06:46.467  tsx0x14c4ea64  ....Transaction created for Request msg CANCEL/cseq=29600 (tdta0x14c51400)
18:06:46.467  tsx0x14c4ea64  ...Sending Request msg CANCEL/cseq=29600 (tdta0x14c51400) in state Null
18:06:46.467       endpoint  ....Request msg CANCEL/cseq=29600 (tdta0x14c51400): skipping target resolution because address is already set
18:06:46.467   pjsua_core.c  ....TX 408 bytes Request msg CANCEL/cseq=29600 (tdta0x14c51400) to TCP 172.30.38.20:5060:
CANCEL sip:4743@172.30.38.20 SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 172.30.0.202:55093;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjwHAvb0PCcoewU7nF.39cL2N5AiMAGrvG;alias

Max-Forwards: 70

From: sip:4742@172.30.38.20;tag=0kqd-cxo2dM8SFv05fxlJH8UGHzXdUZe

To: sip:4743@172.30.38.20

Call-ID: NC.T6KcR7Rv-Sno23807LLcoBn1ZosfT

CSeq: 29600 CANCEL

Route: <sip:172.30.38.20:5060;transport=tcp;lr>

User-Agent: JCT Messenger

Content-Length:  0




--end msg--
18:06:46.469  tsx0x14c4ea64  ....State changed from Null to Calling, event=TX_MSG
18:06:46.469  dlg0x153fe664  .....Transaction tsx0x14c4ea64 state changed to Calling
18:06:46.572 sip_endpoint.c !Processing incoming message: Response msg 200/CANCEL/cseq=29600 (rdata0x14c367d4)
18:06:46.572   pjsua_core.c  .RX 378 bytes Response msg 200/CANCEL/cseq=29600 (rdata0x14c367d4) from TCP 172.30.38.20:5060:
SIP/2.0 200 OK

Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 172.30.0.202:55093;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjwHAvb0PCcoewU7nF.39cL2N5AiMAGrvG;alias

From: <sip:4742@172.30.38.20>;tag=0kqd-cxo2dM8SFv05fxlJH8UGHzXdUZe

Call-ID: NC.T6KcR7Rv-Sno23807LLcoBn1ZosfT

CSeq: 29600 CANCEL

Supported: timer,100rel

Server: IP Office 9.0.6.0 build 979

To: <sip:4743@172.30.38.20>;tag=a747f750afce40c6

Content-Length: 0




--end msg--
18:06:46.573  tsx0x14c4ea64  .Incoming Response msg 200/CANCEL/cseq=29600 (rdata0x14c367d4) in state Calling
18:06:46.573  tsx0x14c4ea64  ..State changed from Calling to Completed, event=RX_MSG
18:06:46.573  dlg0x153fe664  ...Received Response msg 200/CANCEL/cseq=29600 (rdata0x14c367d4)
18:06:46.573  dlg0x153fe664  ...Transaction tsx0x14c4ea64 state changed to Completed
18:06:46.573 sip_endpoint.c  Processing incoming message: Response msg 487/INVITE/cseq=29600 (rdata0x14c367d4)
18:06:46.573   pjsua_core.c  .RX 484 bytes Response msg 487/INVITE/cseq=29600 (rdata0x14c367d4) from TCP 172.30.38.20:5060:
SIP/2.0 487 Request Terminated

Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 172.30.0.202:55093;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjwHAvb0PCcoewU7nF.39cL2N5AiMAGrvG;alias

From: <sip:4742@172.30.38.20>;tag=0kqd-cxo2dM8SFv05fxlJH8UGHzXdUZe

Call-ID: NC.T6KcR7Rv-Sno23807LLcoBn1ZosfT

CSeq: 29600 INVITE

Allow: INVITE,ACK,CANCEL,OPTIONS,BYE,INFO,REFER,NOTIFY,SUBSCRIBE,REGISTER,PUBLISH,UPDATE

Supported: timer,100rel

Server: IP Office 9.0.6.0 build 979

To: <sip:4743@172.30.38.20>;tag=a747f750afce40c6

Content-Length: 0




--end msg--
18:06:46.574  tsx0x15405864  .Incoming Response msg 487/INVITE/cseq=29600 (rdata0x14c367d4) in state Proceeding
18:06:46.574       endpoint  ..Request msg ACK/cseq=29600 (tdta0x14c54400) created.
18:06:46.574   pjsua_core.c  ..TX 396 bytes Request msg ACK/cseq=29600 (tdta0x14c54400) to TCP 172.30.38.20:5060:
ACK sip:4743@172.30.38.20 SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 172.30.0.202:55093;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjwHAvb0PCcoewU7nF.39cL2N5AiMAGrvG;alias

Max-Forwards: 70

From: sip:4742@172.30.38.20;tag=0kqd-cxo2dM8SFv05fxlJH8UGHzXdUZe

To: sip:4743@172.30.38.20;tag=a747f750afce40c6

Call-ID: NC.T6KcR7Rv-Sno23807LLcoBn1ZosfT

CSeq: 29600 ACK

Route: <sip:172.30.38.20:5060;transport=tcp;lr>

Content-Length:  0




--end msg--
18:06:46.574  tsx0x15405864  ..State changed from Proceeding to Completed, event=RX_MSG
18:06:46.575  dlg0x153fe664  ...Received Response msg 487/INVITE/cseq=29600 (rdata0x14c367d4)
18:06:46.575  dlg0x153fe664  ...Transaction tsx0x15405864 state changed to Completed
18:06:46.580    pjsua_aud.c  .....Conf disconnect: 1 -x- 0
18:06:46.580   conference.c  ......Port 1 (ringback) stop transmitting to port 0 (iPhone IO device)
18:06:46.580    pjsua_app.c  .....Call 0 is DISCONNECTED [reason=487 (Request Terminated)]
18:06:46.580    pjsua_app.c  .....Call 0 disconnected, dumping media stats..
18:06:46.580 pjsua_app_comm  .....
  [DISCONNCTD] To: sip:4743@172.30.38.20;tag=a747f750afce40c6

    Call time: 00h:00m:00s, 1st res in 8822 ms, conn in 0ms
18:06:46.580  pjsua_media.c  .....Call 0: deinitializing media..
18:06:46.580  pjsua_media.c  ......Call 0: cleaning up provisional media, prov_med_cnt=1, med_cnt=0
18:06:46.582  dlg0x153fe664  .....Session count dec to 1 by mod-invite
18:06:46.582 tdta0x15403800  ..Destroying txdata Request msg INVITE/cseq=29600 (tdta0x15403800)
18:06:46.582  tsx0x14c4ea64  Timeout timer event
18:06:46.582  tsx0x14c4ea64  .State changed from Completed to Terminated, event=TIMER
18:06:46.582  dlg0x153fe664  ..Transaction tsx0x14c4ea64 state changed to Terminated
18:06:46.586  tsx0x15405864  Timeout timer event
18:06:46.586  tsx0x15405864  .State changed from Completed to Terminated, event=TIMER
18:06:46.586  dlg0x153fe664  ..Transaction tsx0x15405864 state changed to Terminated
18:06:46.586  dlg0x153fe664  ...Dialog destroyed
18:06:46.590  tsx0x14c4ea64  Timeout timer event
18:06:46.591  tsx0x14c4ea64  .State changed from Terminated to Destroyed, event=TIMER
18:06:46.591 tdta0x14c51400  ..Destroying txdata Request msg CANCEL/cseq=29600 (tdta0x14c51400)
18:06:46.591  tsx0x14c4ea64  Transaction destroyed!
18:06:46.591  tsx0x15405864  Timeout timer event
18:06:46.591  tsx0x15405864  .State changed from Terminated to Destroyed, event=TIMER
18:06:46.591 tdta0x14c54400  ..Destroying txdata Request msg ACK/cseq=29600 (tdta0x14c54400)
18:06:46.591  tsx0x15405864  Transaction destroyed!
18:06:47.580    pjsua_aud.c  Closing sound device after idle for 1 second(s)
18:06:47.581    pjsua_app.c  .Turning sound device OFF
18:06:47.584    pjsua_aud.c  .Closing iPhone IO device sound playback device and iPhone IO device sound capture device
18:06:47.637 coreaudio_dev.  .core audio stream stopped
```

Comment: What Avaya system are you using? Have you tried testing any other phone on your Avaya PABX to confirm that the configuration on the PABX is not perhaps causing this? This is a common problem with overlapping dial patterns which causes the PABX to wait for additional digits before commencing with the call.

Comment: Thanks,  it is an Avaya IP office 500. They have a few different devices connected and it only seems to happen to my app. I was able to get around it in the end by using the compact headers option.  Not sure why that worked, but I guess something in the header was causing issues.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?